# email not responsive in gmail IOS

Tags: html, ios, email, gmail

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1">
```

my head of email is like this, I thought this would be enough to have my email responsive in gmail (iOS) ? My html is done properly and I can see the responsiveness when I resize the browser but it render the desktop version when I test that in my device.

Comment: Try add `initial-scale=1` ?

Answer (score 0):

Gmail strips out the `<style>` tag from your HTMl. That means none of your media queries will work. In order to create a responsive email for Gmail, you will need to use fluid techniques. The article below is a bit old, but the techniques still apply.

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/creating-a-simple-responsive-html-email--webdesign-12978